# Is there a plugin for visual studio that can remove source control binding?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, version-control

when opening a solution from a visual studio w/o source control, visual studio just complains about every project in the solution that can't be register with source control, when the number of project is big, it's really annoying.

Comment: What about using File->Source Control->Change Source Control?

Comment: Every SCC provider comes with an 'unbind' option that is available from the VS menu anyway. So I don't exactly understand your question...

Comment: @Thomas, I am using tortoise HG scc: http://bitbucket.org/zzsergant/hgsccpackage/overview, i didn't see such option.

Comment: @R0MANARMY, no i am using http://bitbucket.org/zzsergant/hgsccpackage/overview

Comment: @Thomas - never say never and never say every. hgscc has no such option.

Comment: @poet @Benny: Ok, you got me. I should have said: Every SCC provider _that I know_ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just released HgSccPackage v1.3.3 which have an option to add or remove Scc bindings from projects and solution. Use menu File->Change Scc Bindings, then select projects to remove Scc bindings in the list and press unbind button.

You can download it here: http://bitbucket.org/zzsergant/hgsccpackage/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

Not a plugin but will do the job nonetheless:

Jeff Atwood's [Clean Sources Plus](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/clean-sources-plus.html) and it's successor [TreeTrim](http://code.google.com/p/treetrim/)